# Dynamically register functions with Python C-API

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, cpython

I am looking for a way to have a Python C function register other Python C functions in its module.

Usually functions are declared statically in the shared library using:

```
Py_InitModule(module_name, functions);
```

I add a look at Py_InitModule implementation in cpython and tried to:

- register a module with my first function with Py_InitModule
- have the first function getting the module dictionary:

```
PyModule_GetDict(module)
```

- generate new python function from c functions:

```
PyCFunction_NewEx(&method, (PyObject*)NULL, n)
```

- add the new function to the module dictionary:

```
PyDict_SetItemString(d, method.ml_name, v) != 0
```

However it segfaults miserably when I try to call the new function.

What am I doing wrong ?
Is it even possible to do such thing with CPython ?

To be more precise here is a complete exemple:

```
static int load_extra_methods(void)
{
    PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
        {
             "my_new_method",
             my_new_method,
             METH_VARARGS,
        },
        /* possibly more functions here */
    };
    const char *name = "module_name";
    PyObject *d = PyModule_GetDir(_G.pymodule);
    PyObject *n;

    if(_Py_PackageContext != NULL) {
        char *p = strrchr(_Py_PackageContext, '.');
        if (p != NULL && strcmp(name, p + 1) == 0) {
            name = _Py_PackageContext;
            _Py_PackageContext = NULL;
        }
    }
    n = PyString_FromString(name);

    for (int i = 0; i < countof(module_methods); i++) {
        PyMethodDef method = module_methods[i];
        PyObject *v = PyCFunction_NewEx(&method, (PyOBject*)NULL, n);

        if (v == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(n);
        }
        if (PyDict_SetItemString(d, method.ml_name, v) != 0) {
            Py_DECREF(v);
            Py_DECREF(n);
            return -1;
        }
        Py_DECREF(v);
    }
    return 0;
    Py_DECREF(n);
}
```

This function above is called by another function previously exposed with the usual Py_InitModule3 function.
The code above is heavily borrowed from CPython implementation itself (Python/modsupport.c Py_InitModule4).

**Edit**

I misplaced Py_DECREF(n); (fixed now in the sample code).
Now I have a:

```
SystemError: ../Objects/methodobject.c:120: bad argument to internal function
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete code example